# Postgres how to drop table owned by another user without mirroring that user's Permissions

Tags: postgresql

User A owns all of our tables and has access to all of our schemas

User B needs full access including Drop and Alter permissions to some of those tables and schemas but not all of them.

As is well documented, Drops and Alters are not possible because User B does not own the tables.

```
UserB => DROP TABLE userATable;
ERROR:  must be owner of relation test
```

The [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584640/postgresql-error-must-be-owner-of-relation-when-changing-a-owner-object) in this case seems to be to make Role B a member of Role A.

```
grant UserB to UserA;
```

But we cannot do this because then UserB will have access to schemas for which it should not.  What are recommended strategies to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the tables be owned by role A and grant role A to role B (or make them owned by role C and grant C to both A and B)

Comment: yes this is our current backup plan, but we were hoping there was some other less invasive way to handle this.  it does not seem that there is though, so I will accept this answer

Comment: You could play around with functions (or procedures) having `security definer` and owned by `A` but that seems easy to mess up.